# jQuery TextExt Plugin: KeyPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-textext

I use TextExt, textext.plugin.tags.js

```
jQuery("#InputID").textext({ plugins: 'tags' }).keypress(function (event) {

                      //See if the key pressed is 'enter'
                      if (event.which == 13) {
                         alert("pressed key is enter");
                      });
```

but after press key enter, alert message not displaying

I want to catch keypress enter and KeyUp, some proposal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the `tags` documentation, it appears that you want to use event `enterKeyPress`:

http://textextjs.com/manual/textext.html

I don't believe that `textExt({plugin: 'tags'})` supports the `keypress()` method. Try this:

```
jQuery("#InputID").textext({ plugins: 'tags' }).on({
    enterKeyPress: function(event) { alert('enter!'); }
});
```

Comment: I was having a problem in IE8 with textarea inside a form. When pressing enter, fired the event of the form submit. With this I was able to catch the enter event and include `event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;`. Thank you @dave mankoff!